# List doesn't display element from JSON file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm learning a new Framework (ASP.NET) and his associated language (C#). It's not easy for me, because I only have Python skills and I'm not an object-oriented programming expert.

**Objective:**

By following some tutorials, I'm trying to import data from JSON file into my Model. Then, in my controller, I try to get data and display in the view.

I don't know why, but data are not displayed and I don't have any issue.

This is my model class:

```
namespace Blog.Models
{
    public class Article
    {
        public string Pseudo { get; set; }
        public string Titre { get; set; }
        public string Contenu { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have another class which let to create a list from my articles:

```
namespace Blog.Models
{
    /// <summary>
    /// permet de gérer les articles qui sont enregistrés dans un fichier JSON
    /// </summary>
    public class ArticleJSONRepository
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Représente le chemin du fichier JSON
        /// </summary>
        private readonly string _savedFile;

        /// <summary>
        /// Construit le gestionnaire d'article à partir du nom d'un fichier JSON
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileName">nom du fichier json</param>
        public ArticleJSONRepository(string fileName)
        {
            _savedFile = fileName;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtient une liste de tout les articles
        /// </summary>
        public IEnumerable<Article> GetAllListArticle()
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_savedFile))
            {
                List<Article> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Article>>(reader.ReadToEnd());
                return list;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My JSON file looks like this (very simple):

```
{
    "post": {
        "Pseudo": { "value": "Clem" },
        "Titre": { "value": "mon article" },
        "Contenu": { "value": "Du texte, du texte, du texte" }
    }
}
```

Then, I have my controller named `ArticleController`:

```
namespace Blog.Controllers
{
    public class ArticleController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ArticleJSONRepository _repository;

        public ArticleController()
        {
            string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "App_Data", "articles.json");
            _repository = new ArticleJSONRepository(path);
        }
        // GET: Article
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("Index");
        }

        public ActionResult List()
        {
            try
            {
                List<Article> liste = _repository.GetAllListArticle().ToList();
                Console.WriteLine(liste);
                return View(liste);
            }
            catch
            {
                return View(new List<Article>());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, I have my view named `List.cshtml`:

```
@model IEnumerable<Blog.Models.Article>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/__Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>List</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Pseudo)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Titre)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contenu)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pseudo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Titre)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contenu)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

It gives me:

[image]

If I remove the `try/catch`, it gives me this issue:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Blog.Models.Article]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
>   type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
>   to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'post', line 2, position 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate problem is that your json  file doesn't match the data structure that your asking JsonConvert to produce.  Try a json file of the form :

```
[  
   {  
      "Pseudo":"quelque_chose_1",
      "Titre":"quelque_chose_2",
      "Contenu":"quelque_chose_3"
   },
   {  
      "Pseudo":"quelque_chose_1",
      "Titre":"quelque_chose_2",
      "Contenu":"quelque_chose_3"
   }
]
```

Comment: You're right ! I had to change the syntax from this one `"Pseudo": { "value": "Clem" },` to this one `"Pseudo":  "Clem",`. Now it works !

Comment: @Essex Glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

In your case, your `Model` is incorrect to deserialize the `JSON` string that you have in your question. I have prepared a sample deserialization for your `JSON` string. The code will look like:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json=@"{'post':{'Pseudo':{'value':'Clem'},'Titre':{'value':'mon article'},'Contenu':{'value':'Du texte, du texte, du texte'}}}";
        var Sresponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(Sresponse.post.Pseudo.value);
        Console.WriteLine(Sresponse.post.Titre.value);
        Console.WriteLine(Sresponse.post.Contenu.value);

    }
}

public class Pseudo
{
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class Titre
{
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class Contenu
{
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public Pseudo Pseudo { get; set; }
    public Titre Titre { get; set; }
    public Contenu Contenu { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Post post { get; set; }
}
```

This will yield the following output:

```
Clem
mon article
Du texte, du texte, du texte
```

You can accordingly assign the output to your associated variables in a new `Model` maybe depends on your implementation and send the `Model` to your `View`.

A working DEMO is here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oCuZND

Comment: I'm using asp.net, so firstly I don't have `main` class. Then, I defined data from a json file. And I would like to use class called in my exemple, because I'm following a tutorial and I would like to understand why it doesn't work ;)

Comment: @Essex I know that. This is just an example of how your `Model` should look like for the `JSON` string that is there in your question. You can observe the property names and how they are mapped to the properties in the `JSON` string. From there you can understand how your structure can be parsed. So basically if you use the `Model` in my answer and create your own `ViewModel` to display your parsed data, then you can link them together and send the `ViewModel` to your `View`. The `Model` that you have will not work with the `JSON` because it is a `Dictionary` and not a `string`.